# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-login, sign

I am trying to create facebook sign-in page according to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/) tutorial. I only changed the two lines

```
appId      : '370675846382420', // App ID
channelUrl : '//http://bp.php5.cz/channel.html', // Channel File
```

and I get the following error

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The problem is that whatever url you are currently hosting your app is not setup in your Application configuration. Go to your app settings and ensure the urls are matching.

**Updated**

Steps:

1. Go to 'Basic' settings for your app
2. Select 'Add Platform'
3. Select 'Website'
4. Put your website URL under 'Site URL'

[image]

Comment: I did same as you said above .https://developers.facebook.com/apps/myappid/summary?ref=nav.Here i have mention "example.com" in "App Domains" , and "Website with Facebook Login" - Site URL: is "htttp://example.com" and my html page in which I am calling FB.getLoginStatus is placed at http://example.com/facebookEX4.htm. But still I am gettting same error. Could you tell me what i am missing still ?

Comment: This can happen if you're testing an app on http://localhost/ that's configured in fb to work with www.mysite.com. Go to your hosts file and point www.mysite.com to your ip, and then test it on http://www.mysite.com (which will be your dev environment)

Comment: For me the fix was registering the FULL url!
http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/somepage.php

Comment: Make sure to also put in a port number if you're not using port 80 in localhost server. I'm using 9000 so I had to put in mysite.com:9000 to get it to function

Comment: what if I don't want it to be tied to my URL? I'm making WP plugin and they will host it on their domain.

Comment: Is it possible to register multiple urls ? dev, staging, prod, etc. ?

Comment: Also review Armand's answer below. It cost me quite some time to realize logins are failing occasionally when users type www.mydomain.com into browser instead of just mydomain.com. Had to apply some URL rewrite rules on the server.

Comment: my issue is this can any one help me URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: What should I add into the **site URL**, if I don't have the public domain name yet, but I have the ip address of my VM that running my site. Can anyone please advise ?

Answer (score 23):

This can also happen when the `redirect_uri` submitted with the https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth request is not present in the list of **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** under:

- Settings >> Advanced >> Security

After much trial and error, when I added the `redirect_uri` that I was using (https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html in my case), I suddenly got to the step past this error.

Comment: Thanks, this was my case. Seems like `login_success.html` used to work fine without manually approving it, but they "recently" changed it or something.

Comment: This is super important to remember. The OAuth Redirect URI and the Site URL must be consistent! +1

Comment: @David Alpert you are the man, I can't believe these details aren't always mentioned in tutorials around the web (Android/SDK/Xamarin)

Answer (score 10):

The above answers are right, but you have to make sure you input right URL.

You have to go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

1. Select your app
2. Click settings
3. Enter contact email (for publishing)
4. Click on +add platform
5. Add your platform (probably WEB)
6. Enter site URL

You have two choices to enter: http://www.example.com or http://example.com

Your app will work only with one of them. In order to make sure your visitors will use your desired url, use .htaccess on your domain.

Here's good tutorial on that: http://eppand.com/redirect-www-to-non-www-with-htaccess-file/

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey, what about the part with the "...or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains"? Is this not valid for sharing from websites?

Answer (score 7):

Go to your application, settings (basic tab) and add platform (website). Type your site url and done.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: When I click `Add Platform`, `Website` is greyed out.

Comment: What for this? URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. also it is working in some browsers

Answer (score 6):

Do the above work of adding the site and then the url.
I think the layout of facebook has changed little bit so also do the below things.
- Go to developers.facebook.com -> your app
- Go to Settings->Advanced.
- Under the Security->Valid OAuth redirect URIs, insert all the uri's your app is supposed to redirect to. For example (
`http://localhost:1443/cas/login, https://localhost:2443/cas/login, http://rajanpupa.com/cas/login`
 etc)
- That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I had entered `http://www.example.com` in the App settings. When anybody accessed my website using the full URL, Facebook Login worked fine. But if somebody typed in the URL without `www` in the browser, Facebook Login failed with this error message. When I changed the App Setting to `http://example.com` everything started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and open the app you have created. open setting tab and add platform and insert site url where you want to share facebook button .Its done.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are excellent and accurate.  In the interest of adding to the list of things to try:

Double and triple-check that your app is using the right application ID and secret key.  In my case, after trying many other things, I checked the application ID and secret key and found that I was using our production settings on our development system.  Doh!

Using the correct application ID and secret key fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My Problem Solved by

```
public static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://google.com";
```

it will redirect to Url after ur Login into Facebook.and also you have to reach

url : https://developers.facebook.com -> My App -> (Select your app) ->Settings ->Advanced Setting -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs : "http://google.com".

In the place of "http://google.com" you can place ur respective project Url.so,that it will redirect to your Page.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when trying to run my test web page directly from "file:///C:/webtests/myfile.htm". To fix it, I didn't have to make any changes to my App Settings. Instead, I just had to host my HTML file on an actual server and then hit it like: "http://localhost/myfile.htm".

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the **Facebook Canvas** platform (**Unity WebGL**) and I don't needed to add the Website platform. The only thing I did was add my website root url in:

- Product
- - Facebook Login
- - - Valid OAuth redirect URIs

[image: Facebook Login configurations]

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the "Single Sign On" (can be seen at the bottome of the screenshot in phwd's answer) setting that was turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with the IBM BlueMix SSO service and had to use the BlueMix provided redirect URL as my "site" URL instead of my actually web application site URL to fix it. Once I made that change the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by incorrect app-ID

In my ionic sample I had the same issue because I had inserted a different "app-ID" in my ionic app other than the app-ID I received from Facebook developer account.

so we have to carefully insert the relavent appID

Answer (score 0):

Things have evolved in Facebooks approach, I now realised that you need to
"Add Product" to your App: facebook login. 
make sure oauth & web auth on
add my own site url to ""Valid Auth redirect URI" (and removed the default https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html which his in the

Without this I get the URL Blocked error.