# Get Page and find div contents then display not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

EDIT: this error is caused by my facebook like script, however this script is still not working but without throwing any errors.

I am trying to display part of another page, by using $get and .find jquery functions, however it is giving me an error. I would expect to see if I was linking it to an external domain when I am not.

Here is my code:

```
        var ComponentSrc = "http://localhost/acatalog/8ft_Trampoline_Tent.html";
        $.get(ComponentSrc, function(data){
            $(this).children('div').html($(data).find('.page-content').html());
        })
```

However when running this from the following url: `http://localhost/acatalog/8ft_Fun_Pink_Trampoline.html`

it is giving me this error:

`Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

I realize this error would be displayed if I was  not linking to the same domain however I am not. Is it because its localhost?

Comment: This is not a CORS error, this is a FaceBook API error. Does your page use FaceBook?

Comment: You'll find plenty of examples if you put the error message into the SO search box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345777/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration)

Comment: Aha your right I am getting completly confused, I am using the facebook like, and as its on localhost its giving me this error.

Comment: Also its not a facebook page at all I am linking to, let me check to see if there are other errors that might be stopping this from working

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its contents are removed

Comment: This is a problem with your facebook app settings, change them so you can use it on your localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `$('div#result').load('http://localhost/acatalog/8ft_Trampoline_Tent.html .page-content');` less complicated

Comment: This should be a comment, it has nothing to do with fixing the error.