# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration in Eclipse Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-login

I am using Facebook Login Button by Facebook Phonegap SDk in Android app.

I import Facebook Phonegap SDK as a library project in Eclipse.

I have done all the setting as per below link in www.developer.facebook.com

[Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345777/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration)

When i run Android app in emulator,it display following **error** in console.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. at https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=1234567890&app_id=1234567890&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df3832ed204%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff8897604c%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&client_id=1234567890&display=none&domain&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df102b39294%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff8897604c%26relation%3Dparent%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df155d614cc&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey:1

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the **Advanced Settings**-

1. Switch *Embedded browser OAuth Login* to **YES**
2. Add https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html  in *Valid OAuth Redirect URIs* field.

[image]

Comment: Have you  also added the website platform in the settings?

Comment: yes I have added site URL in website Basic settings

Comment: Please anyone help me.Still i have not solve my problem.