# Facebook AllAuth Django Login

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

First of all I'm fairly new...I've been programming in Django for about a year. I have followed about 6 or 7 Django AllAuth tutorials and think I have a good grasp on setting it up. Although, when I get to the Facebook login, it fails to work. I've set up my Facebook application via Admin, including api key's and app id.

Can I not sign in via Facebook through my localhost? Do I have to be on an external server? I've researched this for about two month and still haven't found any correct solutions to the problem. Very frustrating...Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345777/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration

Comment: Does the App Domain values in your App Settings match your localhost url? Have you created a test app to test locally? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps