# Setting Website Site URL for facebook php applications issue

Tags: php, facebook

I am getting this error:

```
 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of
 the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the 
Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the 
App's domains.
```

This is how i set my website url:
[image]

Why is my url wrong ?  Can someone explain me this part ? thx

**UPDATE**
I tried the following combination:

```
http://attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest/
http://attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest
http://attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest/index.php
http://www.attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest/
http://www.attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest
http://www.attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest/index.php
```

but I still get the error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345777/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration

Comment: Believe me I already checked the first page from google from stackoverflow and I did not found a solution yet

Comment: I believe you thus did not mark the question as a possible duplicate ;)

Comment: I don't believe this question is duplicated. Because all of posts are suggested  that i should go to the website and add a valid url. So I did. And the result is the same :( I still get the error message

Comment: just add the top level domain and check

Comment: like this: http:// www.attila-naghi .com/ ?

Comment: yes and also check this error I got on your site 'Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must enable Web OAuth Login in your App's settings.'

Answer (score 0):

The error appeared because I did not pass the  'redirect_uri' correctly. I missed the ".com" part. So it should look like this:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array ( 
                    'scope' => 'publish_actions,read_stream,user_groups,user_about_me,user_interests',
                    'redirect_uri' => 'http://attila-naghi.com/facebook/mytest/test.php'
            ));
```

and 
 `'Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must enable Web OAuth Login in your App's settings.'`

error message appeared because it must set the **Web OAuth Login**  to **yes** and I must add an url for the **Valid OAuth redirect** URIs field